# Are there any Backpack for Laravel packages that would allow live AJAX CRUD editing?

Tags: ajax, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I really like the focus on responsive tables Backpack has but are there any ways to edit fields inline in a row or add data inline without a new page or a pop-up modal?

Answer (score 0):

No there are not. There have been PRs over the years, but we consider it’s out of scope at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but this is possible now with [Editable Columns](https://backpackforlaravel.com/products/editable-columns), and the feature is quite awesome!